# How to Migrate Spring security from 3.1.2 to 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Existing Spring Boot project *spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.3.RELEASE* and *spring-boot-starter-security version 3.1.2*
I am **upgrading** the project from *jdk 8 to jdk 21*,
*Spring Boot to 3.1.4* and *Spring Security to 6*.

In the existing Spring Boot microservices project, using `TokenStore` (org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore), auth token and roles are stored in redis.
Now TokenStore is not present in the latest Spring Security.
There are more than 20 microservices running in old java version.
There is one gateway which store the token in the TokenStore.

How can I migrate the 20 Spring microservice project one by one? Or shall I do the migration together ?
Is there any way that I can store the token as json in the redis and use it to validate in other microservices instead of Using Token store ?

Comment: Small tip, don't. Do 1 thing at a time, upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 etc. fixing all the small issues in between and keep a running application. When you are at Spring Boot 2.7, upgrade to Java 17 (or 21 should work probably as well). Instead of jumping 10 versions ahead, jumping to newer versions of all the frameworks in use and a newer java version. Things will break and you will have no idea which part of the upgrade broke things. Take smalls steps in your upgrade path instead of giant leaps.

Comment: HI Deinum Thanks for your reply. I agree with what you mentioned. By the way I already migrated 3 Spring boot application to jdk 21 and spring boot 3.1.4 and spring security 6. This is the 4 th one in microservice architecture and due to TokenStore I am facing issues. Spring boot 2.7 will work with jdk 21 ? then I will do that rather than jumping to spring boot 3.1.4. Thanks once again

Comment: I migrated to spring boot 2.7.16 and jdk 21 now getting this error local class and the class which generates the token are different serialVersionUID......Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 420, local class serialVersionUID = 570  any idea how to solve this other than upgrading both to same version

Comment: They are different class so will serialize differently. You can try to use something different then the regular serialization like json or xml.

Comment: class serialization issue is resolved by copying the spring classes UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and SimpleGrantedAuthority in their respective package in local and changing the serialVersionUID in the classes. Project is up and running and working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mr. M Deinum, I upgraded the spring boot version to  2.7.16 and spring security to  5.7.11.

Faced one issue local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 420, local class serialVersionUID = 570
I copied the spring security classes UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and SimpleGrantedAuthority in their respective package in local and changing the serialVersionUID in the classes.